# jQuery print value of variable

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I need some assistance with very simple code. So, I have a string variable that I want to print in the p with listprice class.

```
<script> 

$(document).ready( function() {
var string = "US $257.31";
$('.listprice).append(string);
}
</script>
```

Any ideas how can I achieve that?

Thank you,

H

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this

```
var string = "US $257.31";
$('.listprice').html(string);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/akpn3/

Of course, this assumes there is nothing in the `p` as it would replace everything in there.

To add it on a separate line when the `p` contains content, do this

```
$('.listprice').append('<br />' + string);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/akpn3/1/

**EDIT**

As per your comment

> Do you know how can I do that with regular javascript? I think they
>   are blocking jquery in there.

You could do this

```
var string = "US $257.31";

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

a[0].innerHTML += string;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/akpn3/2/

This finds the first `p` and adds the variable `string`.

Comment: You could do this, but note that it is not functionally equivalent.  This will overwrite anything that is already in the `<p>`.

Comment: Thanks @kingjiv.  I mentioned that.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how can I do that with regular javascript? I think they are blocking jquery in there.

Comment: thanks. Should I be wrapping that code in some kind of function? Or should it just work?

Comment: It will work as long as it is in some `script` tags, preferably at the bottom of the page, so the content loads first.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am working on someone's platform and I am not allowed to use script src tags, so I am limited to use only the code that is permitted by them( and I don't know what that is exactly). I think it won't work. But thanks again!

Comment: what if want to specify a specific tag not the first. can I do <div id="listprice"></div>

and then

var string = "US $257.31";

var a = document.getElementById('listprice');

a[0].innerHTML += string;

Comment: Close! If you change the `div` from a class to an id, it is even easier.  Do this `var string = "US $257.31";` then just `document.getElementById('listprice').innerHTML += string;`.  That's it.  http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/akpn3/7/

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `'`.

```
$('.listprice).append(string);
```

should be

```
$('.listprice').append(string);
```

EDIT: Also missing a `)` at the end.

Other than that it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You've it right except for some typos (and I added tag specifier to make the lookup bit faster):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   var string = "US $257.31";
   $('p.listprice').append(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code will append `US $275.31` to all elements with the `listprice` tag.

If you want to append it only to `p` tags with `listprice`, specify `$('p.listprice').append(...`.

Oh, and remember to close your quotes after the identifier (`listprice`).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't appending (adding an element to another). You just want to change the `p` text.

```
$(".listprice").text(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Also Print Your Variable Value Between String Look like...

```
var filename = $('#resume').val();
$("#msg_show").text("Your resume "+filename+" has uploaded successfully. If you wish to upload a different document, please click the “Submit your Resume” button and select your file again.");
```