# How to parametrize setMedia in jPlayer?

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm trying to use a jPlayer to trigger the player in my template. I need to pass a value to the *mp3* option but I don't know how to set *mp3* in `setMedia` to `music` .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var music = $(".album-playlist li").first().find("input").val();
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: music,
      }).jPlayer("");
    },
    swfPath: "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/beta/libs",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916300/jquery-print-value-of-variable

Comment: That answer doesn't apply to this situation I don't think. I saw it already. I'll close this if you can tell me what I'm missing real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Your question was about how to print a variable, but it seems that you actually want to figure out how to `setMedia` of a `jPlayer`

Check out this link http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-setMedia

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer( {
  ready: function() {
    $(this).jPlayer( "setMedia", {
      mp3: "yourpath/movie.mp3"
    });
  },
  supplied: "mp3"
);
```

In your case all you have to do is move `$music` to the right scope. Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var music = $(".album-playlist li").first().find("input").val();
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer( {
      ready: function() {
        $(this).jPlayer( "setMedia", {
          mp3: music
        });
      },
      supplied: "mp3"
    );
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").append("Mp3: " + music);
});
```

Comment: What can I append it to though? I need it as a value for mp3:

Comment: <div id="musiclabel">mp3: </div>

Comment: Is it just me or does that not make any sense. In the script you can see that it needs a value for `mp3:` which is the url of the mp3 which I get using the var `music` that I'm extracting from my template.

Comment: Changed answer to your real question.

Comment: Ok that still doesn't work though. I used an alert to make sure `var music` was returning the right value but it still doesn't echo it after `mp3:` . `var music` is the url.

Comment: `$("#jquery_jplayer_1").append("Mp3: " + music);`

Comment: I suggest rephrasing the question - I did find another example though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206608/changing-songs-on-jplayer-by-clicking-a-link-hosted-on-amazon-s3

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var music = $(".album-playlist li").first().find("input").val();
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3 : music }).jPlayer("");
    },
    swfPath: "http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/beta/libs",
    supplied: "mp3"
  });
});
```

I moved the music variable to a place it can be defined easier, also removed the dollar sign ($) from music variable you had in your passing values.

If you're curious what music currently holds in it, you can easily find out by inserting alert(music); right after var music. Example:

```
var music = $(".album-playlist li").first().find("input").val();
alert(music);
```

Comment: the alert shows the proper value but it isn't echoing that value after mp3:

Comment: My mistake then, I was under the impression you wanted to know the value. Create a <div id="whateveryouwant"></div> and use CSS to place it where you want. Then in the code you would use $("#whateveryouwant").html(music); That will set the inner HTML of the div to the value